# How to determine linear and nonlinear partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-derivative

How to distinguish linear differential equations from nonlinear ones?
I know, that e.g.:
$$
px^2+qy^2 = z^3
$$
is linear, but what can I say about the following P.D.E.
$$
p+\log q=z^2
$$
Why?
Here $p=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}, q=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

**Definition:** A P.D.E. is called a Linear Partial Differential Equation if all the derivatives in it are of the first degree.

Comment: The examples you gave are not even PDE.

Comment: @AnJin why not PDF? It contains partial derivative terms.

Comment: Because you added sentence later, which when I read it was not add. I cannot assume $p=\partial_x z, q=\partial_y z$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the definition you gave is not widely accepted one. PDE is **linear** if it's reduced form : $$f(x_1,\cdots,x_n,u,u_{x_1},\cdots,u_{x_n},u_{x_1x_1},\cdots)=0$$ is linear function of $u$ and all of it's partial derivatives, i.e. $u,u_{x_1},u_{x_2},\cdots$. So here, the examples you gave are not linear, since the first term of $$-z^3+z_xx^2+z_y y^2=0$$ and $$-z^2+z_z+\log z_y=0$$ are not first order. (in third-order, and second-order, respectively.) However, if you want to use your definition, the first example is ineed linear, (in your definition) and second one is not linear since it's third term is not in first order of $z_y$.